# Makefile variable name convention

Tags: makefile

So I have a directory in my project directory called `bin`, but I also need a variable to hold the directory for where I install binaries, what should I call the latter variable?

```
BINDIR        = ./bin
INSTALL_BINDIR = /usr/bin
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. But I must ask: what is `./lib` for?

Comment: @Beta now that I look at it, it was pretty stupid. I changed it to be `bin` directories.

Comment: I am unaware of any convention covering this topic, at least at the very general level at which the question seems to be aimed.  I have no particular objection to the choices presented in the question, but as far as I am concerned, "what should I call the latter variable?" is primarily a matter of opinion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger there is a subtle and rare consideration regarding `make` variable names: when you want to `.EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES` the ones with anything else than alphanumerics and underscores *nevertheless won't* be exported which you can use to steer your exportation logic.